# sqldatasource and dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 DropDownLists, the first one has a SqlDataSource with only one field, and another DropDownList has a SqlDataSource with a where clause baseed on the selection of the first drop down.

If I press a button the second drop down list populate with the query but how can I make it to populate after selecting an item from the first one.

Comment: Show your code, it always helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can handle the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event of first combo box. And then after building the datasource you can assign it to your second combobox. Like below

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //build your datasource with the query
    comboBox2.DataSource = datasource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use selected index change event of first drop down list to populate the second list

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work in one of my own projects by adding the method for the second-drop-down list's query to a selectionChangeCommited event. Something like this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fillComboBox2();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Your SqlDataSource must have a parameter for selecting its records ("YourParameter")
  //P.E. the SqlDataSource SelectCommand looks like this:
  //"SELECT [id], [name] FROM [table] WHERE [id] = @YourParameter"
  //Include a selectparameter <asp:Parameter Name="YourParameter" Type="Int32" />
  //inside your SqlDataSource. Next, do this:
  sqldatasource2.SelectParameters("YourParameter").DefaultValue = comboBox1.SelectedValue
  comboBox2.DataSource = sqldatasource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
  comboBox2.DataBind()
}
```